# rails ruby iterate through partials in directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, partial

To those helping.. Thanks.  Still no solution but getting closer.  The errors i think are because my "file" evaluates to "app/views/main/show/_partial.html.erb".  and render adds it's own relative path.  So I guess i need to list the file names.. maybe a dir.foreach or dir.glob type command.. i'll keep digging.  THANKS!

I have a directory full of partials I would like to call in a page.  So I wrote a loop but it yields errors.

```
<% Dir["app/views/main/show/*"].each do |file| %>
  <%= render #{file} %>
<% end %>
```

When I replace the render line with a simple

file

it lists the file names so i know the loop and Dir location work.  The problem I THINK is that render is looking for a string.  So I've tried all sorts of things from searching google and here like the #{file}, creating a variable first, raw,...etc.

also I think render may be looking in a different directory relative the Dir.  I'll try out some stuff there to.

How should I be handling this?  I'm up for switching from Dir to Dir.foreach or any other strategy that makes sense.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Here's the solution I've implemented (directory path changed from above):

```
<% Dir["app/views/partials/show/*.html.erb"].each do |file| %>
<p> <%= render 'partials/show/' + File.basename(file,'.html.erb').slice!(1..-1) %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i think it should be <%=render :partial => "#{file}" %>

Comment: whats is the file object you get in the loop . can you print it out for me? and also what are the errors your ares seeing in my above solution doesnt work

Comment: Thanks for helping... files are partials "_part1", "_part2"...etc... error is similar to comment below: Missing partial app/views/main/show/_scene1.html with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/railsProjects/introAnime/app/views"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`file` is already a string, so there is no need to escape. Also, you have to give the full path. This should work:

```
<% Dir["app/views/main/show/*"].each do |file| %>
  <%= render :file => Rails.root.join(file).to_s %>
<% end %>
```

`#{}` only works inside double quotes. E.g. `"#{file}"`, but in this case that's not necessary. You can just use `file`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity but something must be up with the render and DIR reference then..your suggestion yields: Missing partial app/views/main/show/_scene1.html with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/railsProjects/introAnime/app/views"

Comment: looked okay but got this error: Missing partial C:/railsProjects/introAnime/app/views/main/show/_scene1.html with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/railsProjects/introAnime/app/views"

Comment: my relative paths here are killing me!  I think i need to not use the dir["path"].each method as it attached the path to file!

Comment: I don't know. `C:/railsProjects/introAnime/app/views/main/show/_scene1.html` looks like the correct path and according to [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) it should work when it's a full path. The only strange thing is the forward slashes instead of back slashes.

Comment: @twinturbotom, there is one more thing you can try: `render :file => ...`. See my updated answer.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks for sticking with me... is that the right way to approach this or is there a different method or loop setup i should look into?

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with this. `Dir["app/views/main/show/*"].each` seems to be the best way to get all the view files in a dir and `render :file => ...` is perfectly valid too. I would probably do the same.